# Solution to void* and const void* for function parameter -> struct member

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, void-pointers

So I am using this telegram/message dispatcher system for my A.I. which comes from Matt Buckland's "Programming Game A.I. by Example" book.

I have this method for the MessageDispatcher class:

```
void DispatchMsg(double delay, int sender, int receiver, int msg, void *additionalInfo = nullptr);
```

Which then uses a Telegram struct:

```
struct Telegram
    {
        // Messages can be either dispatched immediately or delayed for
        // a specified amount of time.  If a delay is necessary, this
        // field is stamped with the time the message should be dispatched.
        double DispatchTime;

        // Who is sending this message
        int Sender;

        // Who should the component give this message to
        // may be set to -1 if not required
        int Receiver;

        // Message itself, should be one of the several enumerated types
        int Msg;

        // Additional information that might want to be passed along
        void *ExtraInfo;

        Telegram():DispatchTime(-1),
                    Sender(-1),
                    Receiver(-1),
                    Msg(-1)
        {
            // Empty
        }

        Telegram(double time,
                 int sender,
                 int receiver,
                 int msg,
                 void *info = nullptr):DispatchTime(time),
                                        Sender(sender),
                                        Receiver(receiver),
                                        Msg(msg),
                                        ExtraInfo(info)
        {
            // Empty
        }
    };
```

With a cast like:

```
template <class T>
inline T DereferenceToType(void *p)
{
    return *(T*)(p);
}
```

The trouble lies here:

```
void Player::playerFeed() {
        if (!Target)
            return;
        Courier->DispatchMsg(SEND_MSG_IMMEDIATELY, PLAYER_ID, TargetedActor, MessageType::PLAYER_FED, &ActorNode->getPosition());
}
```

Where ActorNode->getPosition() is from Ogre3d Ogre::SceneNode:

```
virtual const Vector3 &     getPosition (void) const
```

Gets the position of the node relative to it's parent.

I then get it back doing:

```
Ogre::Vector3 attackerPos = DereferenceToType<Ogre::Vector3>(msg.ExtraInfo);
```

I would prefer to use a const Ogre::Vector3 here and that can be done writing a const dereference helper function.

Anyway, the problem is:
xxx|90|warning: invalid conversion from 'const void*' to 'void*' [-fpermissive]|

I understand the warning; but I'm not sure how to correct the problem.

I tried fixing it by writing a second method for DispatchMsg:

```
void DispatchMsg(double delay, int sender, int receiver, int msg, void *additionalInfo = nullptr);
// For const void*
void DispatchMsg(double delay, int sender, int receiver, int msg, const void *additionalInfo);
```

But that moved the warning into the function at the creation of the Telegram.
So I tried some things like making a second parameter in my Telegram structure called const void *ConstExtraInfo, the trouble is this seems to make the Telegram structure messy imo.

Basically my question is: is there a clean way implementation for this or if it must be done by having extra members within the Telegram to find out which type of information is stored?

Can it be done with a template for void* or const void* like: Telegram or would this complicate the receiving end of the telegram?

Please let me know if I need to post more information on this.
Thanks.

Comment: Use a `const_cast` to fix the const problem?

Comment: Your `additionalInfo`should be `const void*`. That fixes your problem. Also, use the standard casts, no need to invent your own.

Comment: Yeah that removed the warning :)  Is this the best way to go about it then?

Comment: All right I will try that out; I didn't invent the cast it's the example he had in his book.  It works, and I haven't had any luck with figuring out how to use std casts but I agree with you and would like to, just have to figure that out ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is that the `additionalInfo`-pointer should be `const`-qualified.
Then, your template should also use `const`.
Finally, it should return a reference and not copy the data:

```
template <class T> inline const T& DereferenceToType(const void *p)
{
    return *(const T*)p;
}
```

Anyway, why hide the cast? Instead, do it like this in the receipient:

```
const auto& extra = *(T*)p;
```

Comment: Awesome that worked, what do you mean "hide the cast?"

Comment: @thomas: Just that the template function does so little, using it has more writing and mnemonic overhead than just doing the work at the call site.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean.  Yeah that makes sense, thank you.  It would probably be better to do it there.  Not familiar with auto though, does that just detect what the type is automatically?

Comment: @thomas: Right. Maybe you should get the standard: [C++11 standard plus minor editorial changes.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `const_cast` or a plain C style cast to throw away `const`. This would be the quickest and dirtiest way.

Now, what you are really trying to achieve here is to covert to an intermediate data type that can be cast back and forth from an abstract type to a concrete type. One possible way of doing this is to use what some refer to as a *Variant*, which is a class/struct that holds some opaque data and a tag that identifies this data. Something similar to:

```
enum DataTag {

    DATA_INT,
    DATA_STRING,
    DATA_VEC3,
    // etcetera
};

struct Variant {

    virtual DataTag GetTypeTag() const = 0;

    virtual int AsInt() const = 0;
    virtual string AsString() const = 0;
    virtual Vec3 AsVector() const = 0;

    // same goes for assigning a value. I.e: FromInt()/FromString()
};

template<class T> 
struct VariantImpl : public Variant {

    // add constructors as needed
    VariantImpl(const T & data, DataTag tag)
    {
        this->data = data;
        this->tag  = tag;
    }

    // implement the proper conversions
    int AsInt() const { }
    string AsString() const { } 
    Vec3 AsVector() const { }

    DataTag GetTypeTag() const { return tag; }

    T data;
    DataTag tag;
};
```

Then you could have a pointer to a `Variant` in the `Telegram` struct and set the `ExtraInfo` with:

```
telegram->ExtraInfo = new VariantImpl<int>(42);
```

And then access it at any time with `AsInt()`, as long as you check the type tag first to ensure the conversion is allowed.

From this, you can add a lot to it to fit your needs. Hope it helps.

Comment: I've never heard of this Variant idea, I like it and is a far better way of doing than my messy way.  The only issue is having to do a type for every type of data I will use, and this early in my project I don't know what they all are so I'd have to continue adding them.  I do like the concept though and will have to refer back to this so thanks for taking the time to explain this :)

Comment: You can even throw away the type tag, since the implementation knows the actual type, it is a template struct. The problem with it is that then you can't do runtime type inference. So if for example you have a `VariantImpl<int>` and calls `AsVector()` on it, you'd have to either throw an exception or convert it anyway.

Comment: Btw, here is some more info on the subject: http://www.ojdip.net/2013/10/implementing-a-variant-type-in-cpp/

Comment: I started reading that it's a cool idea, at some point I'll probably want to implement this when I get more time.